# powershell result of 'if condition' write to a outfile

Tags: powershell

In powershell i am writing a script using 'if' condition to check a folder for files received in last 2 hours. The code works fine and the output is written to the screen, instead  i want it to write to a file which can be emailed.
Request for kind help.
Regards
Abhijeet

**EDIT**: Code

```
$f = 'D:\usr\for_check' 
$files = ls $f 
Foreach ($file in $files) 
{ 
    $createtime = $file.CreationTime 
    $nowtime = get-date 
    if (($nowtime - $createtime).totalhours -le 2) 
    {
        "$file"
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is way too complicated. Something like this would be more PoSh:

```
$src = "D:\usr\for_check"
$out = "C:\output.txt"

$append = $false

Get-ChildItem $src | ? {
  $_.CreationTime -ge (Get-Date).AddHours(-2)
} | % { $_.Name } | Out-File $out -Append:$append
```

Comment: @ Ansgar the output.txt returns the ps file name which is check_last2_hrs1.ps1...instead of desired file name that were created in last 2 hours

Comment: I just made some adjustments to the code and checked again, and it does produce the names of the files that were created in the last 2 hours in the directory `$src`. If you get different results: show the code you're using now.

Comment: my mistake i saved and ran the script from the folder which was to be searched....the script file was modified in last 2 hours thats the reason it was showing the script file name..realized and corrected it..Thnks a lot for kind support..

Comment: I suspected that might be the case.  DAMHIKT.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use the redirection operator `>` or [Out-File](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849882.aspx)

Examples:

```
"abc" > c:\out.txt

"abc" | Out-File c:\out.txt
```

Comment: The code 
$f = 'D:\usr\for_check'
$files = ls $f
Foreach ($file in $files) {
    $createtime = $file.CreationTime
    $nowtime = get-date
   if (($nowtime - $createtime).totalhours -le 2)
{"$file"}
}
Gives correct out put but on the screen..if i {"$file" | out-file d:\usr\aaa.out} this gives partial out put compared to that on screen

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the `>>` operator instead of `>` or `out-file` operators as they will overwrite the file every time it's used. Whereas the `>>` operator will write to the file on the next line.

Example:

`$file >> c:\out.txt`

Comment: `>>` is equivalent to `| Out-File -Append`.

Answer (score 1):

Writing each line to the file inside the loop can cause a lot of disk I/O.
You can wrap the loop in a script block, and then output all the lines to the file in one write operation.

```
$f = 'D:\usr\for_check' 
$files = ls $f 
&{Foreach ($file in $files) 
  { 
    $createtime = $file.CreationTime 
    $nowtime = get-date 
    if (($nowtime - $createtime).totalhours -le 2) 
    {
        "$file"
    } 
  }
 } | set-content c:\outfile.tx
```

Comment: @ mjolinor I tried the code you gave but the 'outfile.txt' contains this line check_last2_hrs1.ps1

Comment: Is that one of the files in the directory?

Comment: @ mjolinor found the reason..had saved and ran the script file from the target folder and this was only the file modified in last 2 hours hence was showing the file name..thnks for the kind help though.. :)